# How to get rid of UIAppearance when not needed?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationbar, uiappearance

In my AppDelegate I use UIAppearance to set my own NavigationBar with this code :

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav5.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

But some views of my application don't need it. How can I get rid of it so I may only use IB in concerned views ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need to use the proxy. Just get the actual navigationBar, which should look different and set the colors directly on it.

```
[navigationBarInstance setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[navigationBarInstance setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav5.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

You can also just set both values to `nil`, where you want the standard styles again. (tested by `Ben Clayton`).

```
[navigationBarInstance setTintColor:nil];
[navigationBarInstance setBackgroundImage:nil forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: Setting the background image and colors to `nil` does indeed set the styles back to the default. Tested.

Comment: Doesn't work on `MFMailComposeViewController` instance (See https://alpha.app.net/stuffmc/post/5028278)

Comment: and so you did downvote? its a general question here, not about the mailcomposer..