# Disable UIAppearance for a view controller

Tags: ios5, uiappearance

I would like to disable the UIAppearance override for selected viewcontroller.

Eg. I have a bright orange uibarbutton (Black navbar) which matches my app design. But it doesn't go well with `MFMailComposeViewController` (blue)

Any suggestions? Right now, the UIAppearance setup is at Appdelegate level.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get rid of UIAppearance when not needed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10728594/how-to-get-rid-of-uiappearance-when-not-needed)

Answer (score 0):

I just updating the tint color of the picker as workaround.

```
MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

picker.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[picker.navigationBar setTranslucent:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `appearanceWhenContainedIn:` method of `UIAppearance` protocol. You can even subclass `UINavigationController` for instance, and set the appearance for your subclass without changing `UINavigationController` itself on other Apple classes.